# What is the C++ equivalent of C#'s readonly field modifier?

Tags: c++, field, immutability, readonly

Locking down state is great.  In C# you can ensure that a field doesn't change it's value/reference once the constructor completes by declaring it as `readonly`.

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly string _foo;

    public Foo() {
        _foo = "Unchangeable";
    }

    public void ChangeIt() {
        _foo = "Darn";        // compiler error
    }
}
```

Can I do the same thing with C++?  If so, how?  If not, why not?

Comment: @NicolBolas you closed this as a dupe yet it came first and has four times as many views as the supposed original.

Comment: The target question has much better answers. And that matters more. The accepted answer here is a link-only answer that mentions a keyword, as though that explained everything. The accepted answer there goes into detail about what `const` is and how to use it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That would be [const](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html). Note that this keyword means a couple of different things in different contexts.

Comment: Both links are pretty good (pre/post edit.) Thanks very much.

Comment: Both describe basically the same thing, but the new one is much less negative about the whole thing. Since I like const, I prefer linking to the neutral description ;) If you like my answer, perhaps you could accept it?

Comment: Patience my friend. I generally let a question sit for a while before accepting it to see what other answers surface. Once a question is answered it tends to garner less attention from passers-by.  Enjoy the suspense.

Comment: Good strategy - never thought of that (haven't needed to, since I haven't asked a question yet).

Comment: Consider also: const_cast, which allows you to add or remove const at runtime.

Comment: This answer is wrong. C++'s `const` is equal to C#'s `const` keyword, not `readonly`. You cannot asign a value to a `const` field in the constructor itself in C++, only if you use an initialization list. This renders C++ `const` members useless, because move and copy assignments don't have anything like an initialization list.

Comment: Are you sure move and copy constructors don't have an initialization list? "const and volatile semantics of an object under construction don't kick in until the most-derived constructor completes." It doesn't say what kind of constuctor, move and copy const. are the same: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: As @oddRaven said this answer is wrong! Const in C++ is equivalent to C# const not readonly.

Comment: Christian Rau has the correct answer. There is no equivalent. As seen in Qt (C++), they implement private class pattern using something called a D-pointer to get around this issue.

Answer (score 21):

```
class Foo
{
private:
    const string _foo;
public:
    Foo() : _foo("Unchangeable")
    {
    }
    void ChangeIt()
    {
        _foo = "Darn";        // compiler error
    }
};
```

Comment: The note about identifiers starting with an underscore isn't 100% correct.

Comment: @dalle, it appears you're correct - they're only reserved in the global namespace, not within the context of a class. I'll fix my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: +1, but sorry for being picky.

Comment: @dalle, no need to apologize. Every time I get corrected I learn something, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 15):

There is no such thing directly. You can use a private field with a public getter (but no setter). But that would only apply to other classes calling your code. `Foo` always has full acces to its members. But since you are the implementer of `Foo`, this is no real problem.

Answer (score 8):

It was not immediately clear to me after reading the accepted answer that to make exact equivalent of `readonly` keyword you need to declare the member like this:

```
class Y
{
public:
     void mutate() { x = 7; } // not const member
     int x;
};

class X
{
private:
    Y * const member; // this only makes the pointer to Y const, 
                      // but you can still modify the object itself
public:
    X(Y *m) : member(m) {}

    void f() { member->mutate(); }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

A reference in C++ is not rebindable, so it's equivalent to a C# readonly reference.

Comment: The reference cannot be changed. However, the thing the reference points to can be changed. A member `std::string &s` can be changed perfectly well and the change would propagate to everyone using it.

Comment: @delnan: C#'s readonly works the same way, a readonly StringBuilder can have its contents changed but not be bound to a different StringBuilder.

Comment: No, not really. References can be changed to refer to a completely different object, while a readonly field always refer to the same thing even though this thing may change its internal state. For reference types, it may work similar enough in practice. But the difference is plainly visible with value types, which can be changed with C++ references but not with C# readonly fields.

Comment: C# readonly for value types is an entirely different thing than it is for reference types.  C++ references cannot point to a different object once bound, but changing the value of an int is not pointing to a different object in C++.

Comment: The point is: `x = 0;` isn't supposed to work. With C++ references, it does. With a C# readonly field, it doesn't. (But to nitpick, you're still wrong unless you consider the location - e.g. variable - the reference refers to an "object", which might be valid but isn't useful and beyond what "object" refers to in other languages.)

Answer (score 1):

C++ has `const`, which does the same job as `readonly` in C#.

```
const int Constant1 = 96;    
Constant1 = 200   // Compiler Error.
```

Comment: Is `const` for a local variable (as this example seems to show) the same as `const` for a field, as in the original question?

Comment: Readonly in C# is assigned value in ctr, whereas const is compile-time known value, so they are not the same.

Comment: Const values (both in C++ and C#) are optimized out by compilers. Readonly are not as their values are not known ahead.

Comment: It doesn't do the same job as readonly in C#. Const local or field in C++ has to be initialized when it is defined. Readonly in C# doesn't have to be initialized when it is defined, it can be initialized later in a constructor. You can also only have readonly field and not local variable. Also, const in C# has to be initialized by a constant expression and known at a compile time, as @ОгњенШобајић said.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need as you when doing a transcription from C# to C++
and it is just a syntax error because this instruction exists in C++ ( visual C++)

Syntax : [readonly]

"The readonly C++ attribute has the same functionality as the readonly MIDL attribute.
If you want to prohibit modification of a method parameter, then use the in attribute."

source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45x4ky7s.aspx

source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa367152